# How does ZeroPadding2D layer compute?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network, keras-layer

How exactly ZeroPadding2D works in Keras? If I apply padding=(0,40) attribute to a (96,1366,1) image, I get (96,1440,1), but I don't understand how 1440 is the result from computation.

Comment: can you add the rest of your model?

Comment: Are you sure it's not 1360 or 1446? It's just adding 40 to both sides of your image. 2*40 = 80

Answer (score 2):

It's just adding 40 to both sides of your image (adding 80 in total).

https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#zeropadding2d

I really beleive that your values are either:

- input (96,**1360**,1) and output (96,**1440**,1); or
- input (96,**1366**,1) and output (96,**1446**,1)

Comment: Sorry my bad! I knew the concept but I was referring to the wrong code all the while and hence the confusion arose. Yes (0,40) should be infact (0,37). Thanks!